# Get 2D Gauss–Legendre quadrature points and weights using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

NumPy provides the `np.polynomial.legendre.leggauss()` function to compute the sample points and weights for Gauss-Legendre quadrature. I'm trying to use this function to get the 2D points and weights for a quadrilateral. I am able to use the function as shown here:

```py
def gauss2D(n):
    x, w = np.polynomial.legendre.leggauss(n)

    weights = []
    gauss_pts = []

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            wts = w[i] * w[j]
            weights.append(wts)

            g = [x[i], x[j]]
            gauss_pts.append(g)

    return np.array(weights), np.array(gauss_pts)
```

Which outputs the following for `n=2` integration points:

```
weights
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]

points
 [[-0.57735027 -0.57735027]
 [-0.57735027  0.57735027]
 [ 0.57735027 -0.57735027]
 [ 0.57735027  0.57735027]]
```

If it's possible, I would like to get rid of the for-loops by using NumPy arrays but my attempt (see function below) does not generate the correct results.

```py
def gauss2Dnumpy(n):
    x, w = np.polynomial.legendre.leggauss(n)

    weights = np.concatenate((w, w))

    gauss_pts = np.zeros((n*2, n))

    for i in range(n*2):
        for j in range(n):
            gauss_pts[i] = x[j], x[j]

    return weights, gauss_pts
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without the for-loops?

Comment: Why calculate them?  They don't change.  I'd make them a static lookup.  They've been calculated for you.

Comment: @duffymo Well, it would be nice to just calculate them instead of having a bunch of lookup tables in my code. And the tables get large when n>6. But since you mentioned it, where can I find the 2D lookup tables? They would be helpful for checking my function.

Comment: I couldn't disagree more.  But do what you think is best.  Any text on finite elements would have Gauss points and weights for 1, 2, and 3D cases for linear and higher orders.  Start with this: https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/legendre-gauss.html

Comment: @duffymo That link provides tables for 1D which I can already get from the  `np.polynomial.legendre.leggauss(n)` function. I'm looking for 2D integration points and weights.

Comment: the 2D points are just (X, Y) permutations of the 1D points.  Nothing to calculate.  The weights are products.  I wouldn't calculate them over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be:

```
x, w = np.polynomial.legendre.leggauss(n)

gauss_pts = np.array(np.meshgrid(x,x,indexing='ij')).reshape(2,-1).T
weights = (w*w[:,None]).ravel()
```

Comment: Wow, this is impressive. I didn't know about the `ravel()` function. How did you come up with this?

Comment: Very nice: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html

Comment: @duffymo Based on your comments, you would rather have a bunch of lookup tables instead of three lines of code?

Comment: It's not a matter of three lines of code.  It's executing those three lines of code 100,000 times if I want to generate stiffness matrices for 100,000 elements in a finite element mesh.  Quite likely.  That's the use case where I've written and executed code like this.  It makes zero sense to calculate fixed values over and over again.

Comment: Initialization once?  I'd go for that.  Just not repeatedly.