# How to get Lebedev and Gaussian spherical grid

Tags: python, numpy, mesh, spherical-coordinate

I am being reading some works on HRTF interpolation and spherical harmonics.
In such works regular spherical grids are often used, e.g., in [this work](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/frsip.2022.884541/full), but I am missing how to compute them:
Hence, how to compute the Lebedev and the Gaussian spherical grids?

Is there a python package that easily return the list of points for a specific grid?

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77002315/get-2d-gauss-legendre-quadrature-points-and-weights-using-numpy would cover the Gaussian case

Comment: Gaussian grids are an  _n x m_ grid (_m_ is most of the times _2n_ ), where the longitude is equidistantly spaced and the latitude is spaced according to the Gauss-Legendre quadrature points (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_grid). The question provided by @Chutlhu covers this case.

Comment: the Lebedev grid is a bit more tricky, but there is python code mentioned on the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebedev_quadrature

Comment: Thank you. The easiest way I found is to use the function is `sound-field-analysis-py` lib: https://appliedacousticschalmers.github.io/sound_field_analysis-py/modules.html#generators . Python implementation is provided in the code